# Activated AWS CDN - Keep receiving "X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront"

Tags: caching, cakephp, cdn, max-age

I just activated AWS CDN, and all I see is "X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront".

Also I see "max-age=0" which I don't know where it's coming from. Checking the code (cakePhP), I don't see any place setting max-age. I wonder that's the reason?
Here is the link: https://www.findfestival.com/pryor/rocklahoma-music-festival-info/

---

on the side note, on the front page, I added "max-age=86400" manually in the http code, and max-age=86400 max-age=0  and "Hit from Cloudfront" showed up in the inspector.

https://www.findfestival.com/

If "max-age" is the reason, how can I debug where this comes from.

[image]

Comment: Check your [CloudFront cache settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) and the headers on the response returned by the origin server to Cloudfront.